# Can I upgrade to Windows 10 from my OEM Windows 7 Pro Dell without install media which is currently running Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: windows-7

I received this computer from work for free, its a Dell Vostro 3550 it came with the HD wiped of Windows 7 Pro, which was fine as I wanted a Linux machine. Now I am thinking I'd Like to install Windows 10 and be able to use the OEM product stickers to upgrade to 10. It is running Ubuntu 14.04 right now. Can I do this? Ultimately I'd like to dual boot Win10 and Trusty

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how the PC was originally purchased and how Windows was licensed.

If the PC came with a license for W7 Pro and has a sticker with the code on it, you should be OK to use that code for the upgrade. The OEM license is only valid for that PC anyway.

Comment: I think that PC was purchased by our company as refurb so the OEM sticker says W7Pro, but I am sure they installed and used their enterprise license. I do not have the OEM  install CD/DVD OF W7P, I am not sure how I would be able to upgrade without having a working OS. I am using an illegal copy of W8.1P in virtual box and have that product key but I am sure hundreds of other people are using that key as well. Should I try and contact Dell and maybe they would send me a W7P DVD so I can install a proper and valid OS?

Comment: For W7, you should be able to find plenty of downloadable ISO's on the Internet. Downloading the ISO is perfectly legal and, as you have a license, using it is too. It is certainly possible Dell would send you a DVD (for a cost) but the chances are that the serial # of the PC was registered to your company so they may not talk to you. Do a search, you should easily find the ISO that you can write to DVD.

Comment: AN UPDATE: I was able to get a Win7Pro DVD from Dell posing as our IT guy in June (without cost), and I installed without a problem. I also received my offer to up grade to Win10Pro and I was able to up grade this machine without a problem to Win10Pro. The machine wasn't tied to an enterprise license as it was a refurb with an OEM Win7Pro license.

Comment: AFAIK, the only edition of Windows 7 not eligible for free upgrade is Enterprise. Not sure about Windows 8, but I'd imagine its the same way.

Comment: None of the enterprise versions qualify as they have to be covered by an Enterprise Agreement (EA). That is a totally different licensing model. Your organisation can, however, "top up" from the OEM licenses to EA. A DVD is not a right to use. You need a license. In your case the W7Pro OEM license entitles you to a free upgrade to W10Pro.